# Can I use the wp media uploader for my own plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, javascript, attachments, media

I'd like to use the media uploader within my own plugin and I was wondering if this was possible?

Essentially I'd like the same functionality as found in media-new.php so I can have the same interface to add new files within my plugin as WordPress does.

Apologies for the lack of detail but I'm not sure how else to ask this question.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use `wp_enqueue_media()` in your `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook.

In a javascript file hook it into a button and use `insert` event to capture the selected image's details

```
$('.media-button').click(function() {
    var media_uploader = wp.media({
            frame: "post",
            text : "Add image",
            state: "insert",
            multiple: false
        });


    media_uploader.on("insert", function(){
            var json = media_uploader.state().get("selection").first().toJSON();
            var image_name = json.filename;
            var image_url = json.url;
            var image_caption = json.caption;
            var image_title = json.title;
        });
    });
```